# how to update status active or Unsubcribed of subscriber in _ListSubscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I'm trying to do it this way, but I'm getting 500 error

```ampscript
%%[

var @SubscriberKey, @ListID, @ListType

set @SubscriberKey = "example"
set @ListID= 123 
SET @ListType= "Publication List"

IF Not Empty(@SubscriberKey) THEN

set @UpsertData = UpsertData("_ListSubscribers",3,"SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey, "ListID", @ListID, "ListType", @ListType, "Status", "Active")
OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT("<br>Rows updated: ",@UpsertData))

ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: You can't update dataviews, you would need to make an API call to update this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to just change status for subscriber inside of a list, you will need to use SFMC SSJS Core functions or WSProxy. You can use the AMPScript API functions, but this is highly inefficient and requires a ton of unnecessary processing.

For Core, you would look at using List.Subscribers:

For making a user active, you would want to do [**List.Subscribers.Update**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listSubscribersUpdate.htm) like so:

```js
var myList = List.Init("myList");
var status = myList.Subscribers.Update("mySubscriberKey","Active");
```

For unsubscribing, you can use the Core function [**List.Subscribers.Unsubscribe**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listSubscribersUnsubscribe.htm) like so:

```js
var myList = List.Init("myList");
var status = myList.Subscribers.Unsubscribe("mySubscriberKey");
```

One note on this is that if you are trying to create an unsub event (tying the unsubscribe to a job with reason, etc.) then this is not your preferred path. You will want to use the '**[LogUnsubEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm)**' API call. This is best accomplished via WSProxy:

```js
<script runat="server">
try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    /* Set ClientID */
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid}); //Impersonates the BU

    var props = [
       { Name: "SubscriberKey", Value: "sample@sample.com" },
       { Name: "EmailAddress", Value: "sample@sample.com" },
       { Name: "JobID", Value: 18099 },
       { Name: "ListID", Value: 8675309 },
       { Name: "BatchID", Value: 0 }
    ];
    var data = prox.execute(props, "LogUnsubEvent");
    
    Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(data));
} catch(e) {
    Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

**[Here](https://gortonington.com/logunsubevent-and-how-to-do-it-in-wsproxy/)** is an article I wrote about doing it.

That being said, if you are looking to do the changes in bulk, then WSProxy is the better way to go as it has batch options.

```js
<script runat="server">    

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var subArr = [];
  var myArr = //my Array containing the sub info needed to be changed
 
  for(i=1;i<myArr;i++) {
    //iterate through your 'myArr' to grab the correct info and insert into below
    var subObj = {
        SubscriberKey: subkey,
        EmailAddress: email,
        Lists: [{
            ID: '12345',
            Status: 'Active'
        }]
    };
    subArr.push(subObj);
  }
 
  var options = { 
    SaveOptions: [{
      PropertyName: "*",
      SaveAction: "UpdateAdd"
    }]
  };

 var resp = prox.createBatch("Subscriber", subArr, options);
</script>
```

If you desperately want to do it via AMPScript API functionality, I would look at **[this article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/06/unsubscribe-and-log-an-unsubevent-with-a-logunsubevent-execute-call/)** by Zuzanna that details out the LogUnsubEvent calls for you in both AMPScript and SSJS.

Comment: Wow... Thanks Gregory for sharing the detailed knowledge on possibilities of list updation along with when to use them... Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can achieve this. But due to the simplicity and I prefer to use **[WSProxy](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/introducing-wsproxy-salesforce-marketing-cloud-eliot-harper/)** method as below.

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5"); 

//Making use of Web-socket Proxy
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};

//Similar to RequestParameter in AMPscript to get values from Form submitted
var sub_key = Platform.Request.GetFormField('subkey')
var email = Platform.Request.GetFormField('email')

function unsub() {
prox.setClientId({ "ID": "10966194" }); //Setting MID
var props = { 
                SubscriberKey: sub_key,
                EmailAddress: email,
                Lists: [{ID: '1753',    //Setting your LIST_ID
                        Status: 'Unsubscribed' // to unsub = "Unsubscribed" to subscribe = "Active"
                        }]
            };
var data = prox.updateItem("Subscriber", props, options);

return data.Results[0].StatusCode;
}

unsub(); //Run the above custom function
</script>


Received value subkey = <ctrl:var name=sub_key /> <br/><br/>
Hi User, your email address <ctrl:var name=email /> has been unsubscribed.
```