# Prefence page hosted on SFSC - how to push unsubscribe data back to Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, sales-cloud, unsubscribe

We host our preference center in Sales Cloud (visual force page). The unsubscribes are synced to Marketing Cloud via the Individual Object (automation studio).

What we miss is tracking for each email, how many subscribers have unsubscribed (this in only shown for unsubscribe replies) and not for those who have unsubscribed via the custom prefence page.

How can we make sure this unsubscribe info (including the email ID(?)) is pushed back to SFMC? I know this is possible via the API but it is still vague for me..

Thank you very much!

Comment: This might help (check out the answer by @Gortonington) .... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312263/how-to-update-status-active-or-unsubcribed-of-subscriber-in-listsubscribers

Comment: As Vishal points out, you need to use the SOAP API to do a LogUnsubEvent. The challenge you'll have is that in order to do this, you'll need to have access to the JobID, ListID, BatchID and SubscriberKey. SFMC Landing Pages have access to these through the "Context" provided in the encrypted query string of a wrapped link. You could potentially add these as query string parameters to provide to your VF page. An alternative would be to create a Marketing Cloud page that has ready access to these variables, does the LogUnsubEvent and then redirects off to your VF page.